# SPFx Angular Routing Issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, angular2

I have created SPFx webpart with angular2 and implemented routing and navigation but facing issue as below image:

**Error:**

[image]

**1. WebPart structure:**

[image]

**2. app-routing.module.ts file**

[image]

**3.app.module.ts file**

[image]

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503805/zone-js344-unhandled-promise-rejection-failed-to-load-app-template-html-in-ang/45303366#45303366). Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I have already refereed this link but not working

Comment: Please check if you have passed the correct relative URL for dashboard.component.html in `templateUrl`.

Comment: I have passed templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html'

Comment: Try passing complete absolute URL or `./dashboard/dashboard.component.html`

Comment: Still same error:  GET https://localhost:4321/temp/dashboard/dashboard.component.html 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Component.ts file have to change template url like this**

[image]

**Instead of,**

[image]